Fundamental group of the mapping cylinder of a map between circles
Let’s assume a map $f:S^1 \rightarrow S^1$ is such that $z$ gets mapped to $z^i$ for $i \geq 1$. I want to consider the mapping cylinder $M_f$ and put a CW structure on it to calculate its fundamental group. I can think of the following:

two 0-cells, $x_0$ and $f(x_0)$.
two 1-cells $e_1$ and $e_2$ attached to $x_0$ and $f(x_0)$, and another 1-cell $e_3$ connecting $x_0$ to $f(x_0)$.

How do I attach my 2-cell, and using that to calculate the fundamental group using Van Kampen? I struggle with attaching 2-cells in general.

You do not need a CW structure. The mapping cylinder of a map $f : X \to Y$ is homotopy  equivalent to its base $Y$ (in fact, $Y$ is a strong deformation retract of  $M_f$). Thus $\pi_1(M_f) \approx \pi_1(Y)$.
In your eaxmple you get $\pi_1(M_f) \approx \mathbb Z$.
